# Photoshop Adjustment Layers to Action

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is there a way to make an action of pre-made adjustments layers? I have about 10 adjustment layers set with different blending modes and opacities (basic stuff, no masks etc), but would rather not go through the process of re-configuring these adjustments for when I create this action. Would rather have it as an action command rather than copying the layers from a other psd.

I wasn't planning on making an action, but the adjustments work well across multiple photos.  Hopefully I haven't made a tedious mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

**How to make action:**
http://www.dpandi.com/actions/index.html

**Essentially:**

- Start recording the Action.
- Make Adjustment layer ( or Image Adjustment ) - Just as you normally would.
- Stop recording the action and you're done.

---

I would say **Most** Adjustment Layers do have the ability to save the settings and in that case, I think it doesn't take too much time to load saved settings.. So it might be good idea to utilize that feature. Save and Load buttons, *if* available can be found on the right side of the Adjustment Layer window and works just as you would expect.

At least in some versions `Channel Mixer` and `Black & White` have the Save and load next to Preset dropdownlist on the right in a little icon.

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't even realize you could save the settings for Black & white and Selective colour. Saved me a lot of time. Thanks again!